# Change Shipping Method order

Tags: expresso-store, shipping, ups-shipping

We are using  the UPS plugin, as well as a default shipping method and need the default method to come after UPS during checkout. Is this possible?

Comment: What you mean? It depends on how you coded the template front-end.
In the shipping settings page, it should be possible to drag the order of elements.

Comment: We are simply using the shipping methods tag to auto output them so that they pull the latest UPS methods. If we hardcode this, won't the UPS options possibly not be up to date or show when they shouldn't show?

Comment: I don't think it will show outdated options since you might hardcode a select with just the shipping_method_id. https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/checkout_tag.html#shipping_methods